# Asking a number of patches to do something without using `ask patches`

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to change the color of a number of patches within an area (number controlled by a slider). The if-statement checking coordinates is within an `ask patches` command. When I say `set pcolor` to the variable, it works perfectly. However, when I add another `ask patches` inside the if statement to ask variable number of patches to set their color, I get an error that only observer can ask patches to do anything. My research did not tell me how I could ask a certain number of patches to change color without `ask patches`. Does anyone know how I could work around this?

Answer (score 1):

Almost always, it is a logic error to ask each patch to ask every patch to do something.  That is why it raises an error.  If you want to ask all patches that meet a condition to do something (like change color), you can use `with` to filter the patches.  https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#with